# What did Edgeshot do to Kurogiri in season 3 episode 9?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In season 3 episode 9 Tomura calls Kurogiri who is tied by Woods to do something and it seems Edgeshot pierces Kurogiri and he fell sleep. What did Edgeshot to Kurogiri exactly? How is he supposed to be sleep and not death?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that edgeshot while in his needle form pierced kurogiri and strangled one of his internal organs to knock him out without killing him. To do this he could have performed a blood choke around his corotid artery to prevent blood from getting to his brain. Another possibility would be to knock him out by choking his supply of oxygen. A shot to the liver will also cause great pain without death, however this is less likely thn the others because it does not guarantee a knockout.